# How do I ignore fail so that it can proceed to next step for using pipe. (Bitbucket Pipeline)

Tags: pipe, bitbucket, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

How do I ignore the error so that it can proceed to next step.

Why I want to ignore :

- This pipeline is for development environment.
- There is few of other issues need to be fix first, so some code need to be deployed first without waiting for security fix.
- The security fix is scheduled to fix at agreed time ( so there is few of other code need to be deployed first) .

As you can see above it didnt go to Compress build step.:

[image]

```
- step: 
name: Atlassian Security Scan
clone:
  enabled: true
script:
  - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.6.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `after-script` for that. It runs regardless if `script` fails.

```
- step: 
  name: Atlassian Security Scan
  clone:
    enabled: true
  script:
    - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.6.0
  after-script:
    - echo "clean up"
```

Source: https://bitbucket.org/blog/after-scripts-now-available-for-bitbucket-pipelines